# How can I access the logged in user from outside of a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, signalr

I'm using SignalR to process clicks from the client on my MVC3 application.

Every time a user clicks something, I need to verify the logged in user.

If this were inside an MVC3 controller, I would go:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;

    //My code here.
}
```

However, this code execution is not inside a Controller class.

Basically, how can I access the logged in users name from outside a controller?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Basically, how can I access the logged in users name from outside a controller?

It depends from where you want to access them. If you don't have access to an `HttpContext` you could always try an `HttpContext.Current.User` and pray that it won't be null for some reason like for example different thread or something else. This is especially more possible with SignalR which depends on Tasks and lots of asynchronous processing. If it is inside a SignalR's hub you have access to the user:

```
public class Chat: Hub
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        string username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Personally I wouldn't recommend you ever using `HttpContext.Current`. Depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve and where I guarantee you that there are better ways.

Comment: I've tried it out using HttpContext.Current and it works. What are some of pitfalls you describe? How would it the context be null? Why do you recommend I never use this?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, the context will be null if the code you are executing is for example on some background thread. You didn't answer my question: where are you trying to access this information?

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying, Context is part of the Hub class. Is this what you mean? I should use `Context` instead of `HttpContext`?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, if you are inside a Hub you could use  `Context.User.Identity.Name` to get the currently connected username.

Comment: That's fantastic, some very smart people worked on this library. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, please don't use HttpContext.Current :)

Comment: What's a better way of doing Context.User.Identity.Name in an action filter? I must admit, I've never had an issue with using this to store the id of a logged in user.