# .net check if user is logged in signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Is there a way to check whether a user is logged on in a hub?.

I know I could use this, however HttpContext is not available in the hub:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

-The issue is that I'm sending data to bunch of users and suppose that one of the clients is inactive for a while and his/her session expires.

What I would like to do is in my Hub => Send() method (that gets called from an event), check if the user is still logged in, if not I would send a message to his/her browser to reload a page.

Comment: There is a way in hub class like this; `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. It may help.

Comment: So, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity works for you with signalR outside of the Hub? I cannot get mine to work. HttpContext.Current.User is null for me when I use SignalR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Authorize attribute on your hub if you only want authenitcated users to be able to connect/send to the hub. If you want to get the current user then you just need to access Context.User (it's a property available on the hub).

Answer (score 1):

you can check using `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void send(string message)
    {
        Clients.addMessage(message);
    }

    public void securesend(string message)
    {
        if (this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // secure send.
        }
    }
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991035/securing-signalr-calls)

Comment: This does not prevent random clients from connecting, I think. However, this does show how client methods can be selectively restricted.