# Mapping SignalR connections to users

Tags: asp.net, notifications, signalr, signalr-hub

Consider a web application like facebook, that can send realtime notifications to users.

What is the best way, using [asp.net SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki), to keep track of which connection ids belong to which  user, even if the user disconnects, or reconnects later ?

Comment: It seems to me that you shouldn't need the connection id - you use authentication to get the user, then add the connection to whatever groups the user should receive messages from. Where did the requirement to have the connection id come in?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check out the following blog post:

[Mapping ASP.NET SignalR Connections to Real Application Users](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/mapping-asp-net-signalr-connections-to-real-application-users)

Briefly, you would be adding the connection ids to user on the `OnConnected` method and remove that connection on the `OnDisconnected` method. Keep in mind that an application user can have multiple connections. So, you need to have a one to many relationship between your user and the connection ids. The above linked post explains it in details with a sample.

Comment: Thanks, great example. Marked as answer because of well explained sample code provided.

Comment: Nice blog post, but this is also exactly what I was describing. The only difference is my original answer also works for signalR scenarios where you aren't using http context (such as .net to .net clients). The point being you need to track the information yourself

Comment: @devshorts where did I use `HttpContext` there?

Comment: @tugberk, I was under the impression that the signalR context is a copy of the http context of the user. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289724/how-can-i-access-the-logged-in-user-from-outside-of-a-controller, and https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/108. Either way, I'm not deriding the blog post (I think it's really good), just saying my answer mentioned the same things just without code examples :)

Comment: @devshorts no it's not `HttpContext`.

Comment: @tugberk, I don't like the idea of creating separate objects in a separare list, I would like to extend the applicationuser class with more properties like connectionId. I will post an answer on the way I did it. Although I ran into some exceptions related to entity framework I don't understand.

Answer (score 7):

I did this for an internal app.  The way I did it is that when a user connects, I have the server ask the user to register themselves.  This way I know that not only a user is connected and their signalR connnectionID, but they can also tell me any other information (like username or whatever).

When they reconnect I ask them to do it again.

SignalR will maintain the same connectionID per client even if they reconnect which is nice.  A reconnection is not the same as an initial connection. New connections indicate a new client, but a reconnection is on the same client.

In my app I maintained a seperate threadsafe dictionary that I kept track of which user and which connectionID was doing what.  This way I can say "oh, send message to user ABC" and look up their connectionID. Then act on the Hub's clients object in signalR for that connectionID.  If you do it this way you can even have the same "user" in mutliple connections. Imagine user "abc" is open in two browser tabs.  If you went strictly by connectionID they'd be technically two different users. But, by maintaining some sort of local collection grouping users and connections you can now have multiple connections for the same user.

I should mention that if you do it this way, you should make sure your site handles what happens when it restarts and loses all the connection information.  For me, when someone reconnects I ask them to again re-identify themselves.  This way I can re-build my local dictionary when the server comes online without worry.  It does have more overhead because now you are asking all your clients to send information to you, but depending on your user case this could be staggered or bunched or otherwise distributed to help you handle load.

In general, however you get local information (whether by asking the user to supply it), or by http context session info, you need to track it yourself.

Comment: You say SignalR will maintain the same connection id even if they disconnect or reconnect. 
I just did a test on this with the chat sample they provide, Clients.Caller.newMessage(Context.ConnectionId);
,and I get a new connection id on each page refresh.
So, is it really the same id ? It would be great if it was so

Comment: Daniel, try staying on the same page and turning your network connection off.  When the client disconnects and reconnects they'll get the same ID.  They won't get the same id across page loads. At that point they're a new client.  If this is the workflow you have you should do something like I recommended and have the user identify who they are so you can keep track of who is who

Comment: I think I got it now, please tell me if this is correct, before marking as accepted response:

1) on each page load, refresh, etc, send from client side to server a message to a hub method. 
2) in the hub method, associate the connection id to a cookie or session that holds the website user id
3) store this in a dictionary (key is website user id, value is a signalr group of connection ids)
4) hold this dictionary of user ids => signalr group ids in server memory (session) and update it with latest signalr connection ids received from client side
5) notification is sent to group.

Comment: Yup! That's the general idea.

Comment: One more issue I stumbled upon: How do you get or set Session or Cookies values inside a signalr hub class ? That's the whole point of the association to connection ids.

Comment: @DanielHursan, I stored a dictionary of like Dictionary<username, List<string>> where the string list is the connectionID's.  In your hub class add some logic to add/update/remove from this dictionary as clients reconnect/connect/disconnect. Then use your dictionary to act on the hubs. For session or cookies, not sure how you are trying to get that information, but assuming you can get some sort of "key" you can store that.  You may be able to get a unique idenfitier from the http context

Comment: Hi, If I have multiple pods(containers) how can i store connection ids

Answer (score 3):

Well I used a different approach, I extended the ApplicationUser class like that:

```
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    //public string Address { get; set; }
    //public string City { get; set; }
    //public string State { get; set; }
    //public string Zip { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ChattingUserConnectionId { get; set; }
    //public string HomeTown { get; set; }
    //public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

And in my hub i'm doing something like that:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    #region Data Members
    private static ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private static UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext));
    private static List<ApplicationUser> connectedUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
```

And when a user connects to the chat, I get his ApplicationUser object by his user name and add it to the connectedUsers list. When he disconnects, I remove him.

I ran into some random exceptions with EF states and such which made me create the ApplicationDbContext and UserManager each time it is accessed instead of setting it in a static object:

```
 private ApplicationUser GetCurrentUser()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext));
        var userName = Context.User.Identity.GetUserName();
        var user = userManager.FindByName<ApplicationUser>(userName);

        return user;
    }
```

Edit:

The hub code has some problems loading child objects of the user. This code which is also used in the asp.net template will work better, ApplicationDBContext is not needed:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }


    var user = _userManager.FindByName<ApplicationUser, string>(userName);
```

Comment: it would be great if u provide full code or give link from where we can download the full running code. thanks

Comment: I can't give you the full code, if you have specific question just ask, just use the asp.net mvc template and add a hub and use the code I posted in the relevant places.

Comment: if we do not get full code then it will be bit hard to understand.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. The same user can be connected from multiple browser tabs which would each share the same ASP.NET session (that is just how web browsers work) but have discrete connection IDs.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that. So how can we resolve it? I can check in code if user is already connected and return an error.

Comment: There's a whole new `User ID Provider` in SignalR 2. This article shows all the different ways to map users to connections http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good article on ASP.NET's SignalR tutorial section. 
I've included the introductory paragraph below.

> #### [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)
>
> Each client connecting to a hub passes a unique connection id. You can
>   retrieve this value in the Context.ConnectionId property of the hub
>   context. If your application needs to map a user to the connection id
>   and persist that mapping, you can use one of the following:
>
> - The User ID Provider (SignalR 2)
> - In-memory storage, such as a dictionary
> - SignalR group for each user
>
> Permanent, external storage, such as a database table or Azure table
>   storage Each of these implementations is shown in this topic. You use
>   the OnConnected, OnDisconnected, and OnReconnected methods of the Hub
>   class to track the user connection status.

**UserID Provider**

If you're using ASP.NET's standard membership provider (`IPrincipal.Identity.Name`) you can just do the following to access a client based on a user account. If you have your own user system you can create your own provider.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string userId, string message)
    {
        Clients.User(userId).send(message);
    }
}
```